# Mac Appstore online search?

Tags: mac-appstore, open-source

Is there a website for the Mac Appstore than I can search to see what apps are on it?

(I don't have a Mac, and I'd like to see if an open-source project is on the Mac Appstore.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes luckily there is, it is called fnd with the URL address https://fnd.io/